# SELECT WHERE filter is not applied after using a LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join

Say I have three tables `transactions`, `items` and `users` that looks something like this

```
#items

id  brand  price   transaction_id
--+------+-------+---------------
1  apple    10          1
2  apple    20          2
3  pear     15          1
4  banana   20          1
```

```
#transactions
id   user_id
--+------+
1    1    
2    1  
3    2
4    1
```

```
#users

id   system   value
---+---------+-------
1    gooogle   001
1    facebook  jashd28
2    google    002
2    facebook  jlak30
```

I then want to join those together such that I can see which (google) user has purchased what brands. Currently my query looks like

```sql
SELECT items.transaction_id,items.brand,users.value, items.price  FROM items
LEFT JOIN transactions 
    ON transactions.id= items.transactions_id
LEFT JOIN users
    ON users.id=transactions.user_id
    AND users.system='google'
WHERE items.transaction_id=1
AND LOWER(items.brand) LIKE '%apple%' OR LOWER(items.brand) LIKE '%pear%'
```

(the query above is not 100% the same as mine, but the structure is the same; multiple joins and then a WHERE clause at the end)

but it returns `transaction_id` other than `1`. I can put that `items.transaction_id` into the `JOIN` but then it seems to return all items from `transaction_id=1` and not the `apple` or `pear`

Expected:

```
id brand price user
--+-----+-----+-----
1  apple  10    001
3  pear   15    001
```

Outcome:

```
id brand price user
--+-----+-----+-----
1  apple  10    001
2  apple  20    002  #<- should not be there since it does not have transaction_id=1
3  pear   15    001
4  banana 20    001
```

Comment: use parentheses: `AND (LOWER(items.brand) LIKE '%apple%' OR LOWER(items.brand) LIKE '%pear%')`

Comment: @forpas pfft, perentheses; the posh term for "brackets" ahahhah :-) *edits my answer to sound smarter*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement as shown is:

```
SELECT items.transaction_id,items.brand,users.value, items.price  FROM items
LEFT JOIN transactions 
    ON transactions.id= items.transactions_id
LEFT JOIN users
    ON users.id=transactions.user_id
    AND users.value='google'
WHERE items.transaction_id=1
AND LOWER(items.brand) LIKE '%apple%' OR LOWER(items.brand) LIKE '%pear%'
```

Your problem is that it is showing values that do not have `items.transaction_id = 1`

The reason is because you are mixing up `AND` and `OR` SQL qualifiers and because you are not correctly bracketing (*with parentheses*) them the ordering matters, so you're doing in effect:

```
WHERE (
       items.transaction_id=1
    AND 
       LOWER(items.brand) LIKE '%apple%'
     )
 OR LOWER(items.brand) LIKE '%pear%'
```

Your `AND` statement should use *parentheses* because you have an `OR` qualifier; so you need to construct the syntax logic of `AND ( x OR z )`

so:

```
WHERE items.transaction_id=1
    AND ( LOWER(items.brand) LIKE '%apple%' 
          OR LOWER(items.brand) LIKE '%pear%')
```

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by Martin in above question one problem is the parenthesis are missing.
Secondly you need to where condition apart from JOIN.
So the final query would be

```
select distinct i.id, i.brand, i.price, u.value from items i
left join transactions t
on i.transaction_id = t.Id
left join users u 
on u.ID2 = t.user_id 
where i.transaction_id = 1 
and (i.brand like '%apple%' or i.brand like '%pear%')
and u.system = 'google'
```

[image]

Comment: This potentially completely changes the result set of the query and I can't see that this change is required by the OP.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.